# elasticsearch full text search on property with base64 encoded string

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, base64

i have an elasticsearch index with a property, value of which is base64 encoded (basically contents of a file). like below

```
"file": {
        "_content":"absbdasdjsah94jaksdhkahdkahdP" 
        }
```

i want to be able to perform full text search on that value but i am not sure how to proceed. what i dont want to do is read that value in a server side object, decode it and then perform a full text search (which would mean not using elasticsearch to do the querying).

any feedback, opinions on this are much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check [mapper-attachments](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html) plugin

The ingest attachment plugin lets Elasticsearch extract file attachments in common formats (such as PPT, XLS, and PDF) by using the Apache text extraction library Tika.

The source field must be a base64 encoded binary. This way you can get your base64 encoded data searchable.

PS : what you see in _source is not what you get indexed

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will give this a go and come back.